# how to remove leading 0 record in each group pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, strip

suppose there are record

| index | order | group | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | A | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | A | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | A | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | A | 2 |
| 6 | 6 | A | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | B | 0 |
| 8 | 2 | B | 2 |
| 9 | 3 | B | -1 |
| 10 | 4 | B | 0 |
| 11 | 5 | B | 2 |
| 12 | 6 | B | 4 |

I would like to exclude leading 0 record Data in each group

Expecting result

| index | order | group | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 | A | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | A | 2 |
| 6 | 6 | A | 1 |
| 8 | 2 | B | 2 |
| 9 | 3 | B | -1 |
| 10 | 4 | B | 0 |
| 11 | 5 | B | 2 |
| 12 | 6 | B | 4 |

how do I approached for this? I saw lstrip() but it only applied in each record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html) with comapre for not equal `0` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['Data'].ne(0).groupby(df['group']).cummax()]
print (df1)
    index  order group  Data
3       4      4     A     1
4       5      5     A     2
5       6      6     A     1
7       8      2     B     2
8       9      3     B    -1
9      10      4     B     0
10     11      5     B     2
11     12      6     B     4
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I didn't expected to using cummax() like this.

Comment: `df['Data'].ne(0).groupby(df['group']).cummax()` already relates to "is not leading zero" boolean values, so another `ne(0)` at the end is not needed (doesn't change anything)